# Inserting " in Objective-C string

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to place the following json text in a string in objective c. How do I do this ?

I need 
NSString jsonText = { "username" : "Test", "password" : "testing123" }

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSString *jsonText = @" { \"username\" : \"Test\", \"password\" : \"testing123\" }";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should escape the quotation character and add @ before the string literal so that your code becomes

```
NSString *jsonText = @"{ \"username\" : \"Test\", \"password\" : \"testing123\" }";
```